# What does concatenating an empty string to a string do?

Tags: vba

I've come across this convention in some code I'm editing where they frequently concatenate an empty string to an existing string when assigning it to another variable.

For example:

```vb
Dim var1
Dim var2 = "string"
var1 = var2 & ""
```

I can't think of a reason why they would do this since `&` already makes the result a string. Is there any reason why this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a reason to do it exactly as you show, but this is a pattern you sometimes see used to coerce something into a string type - for example when working with database recordsets:

```
blah = rs.Fields("foo").Value & ""
```

where there's a chance that the field value may be `null` and you just want an empty string instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator

> If an expression is not a string, it is converted to a String variant.
>   The data type of result is String if both expressions are string
>   expressions; otherwise, result is a String variant.
>
> If both expressions are Null, result is Null. However, if only one
>   expression is Null, that expression is treated as a zero-length string
>   ("") when concatenated with the other expression. Any expression that
>   is Empty is also treated as a zero-length string.

Comment: It's still ugly as hell though. Use `ISNULL` in the T-SQL (assuming SQL Server; `Nz` function in Access) to coalesce `NULL` values into empty strings *server-side*, so the VBA client doesn't need to do such gymnastics. So the short version would be "Unless you're dealing with `Null` values, there's no need for this"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just came across this for the first time. I've used a home-grown version of NZ since Access 1.0. Now that NZ is built-in to Access (since 2003), that's what I use. I'd say there's no reason to use this construct at all - NZ more clearly indicates your intention.

Comment: I would agree *assuming* you have control of the source statement for the recordset.